# Meteor can't exit method

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm not being able to exit a method when returning an alert. For example i have here two validations "hasEventWithExternalId" and "isValidFacebookEvent",if i try the same event more than once the result of "hasEventWithExternalId" turns true and it returns the alert, but then the execution of the method continues and creates a new event and returns the success alert. Any ideas on wahts happening?

```
Template.eventnew.events({
    'click #btn-event-data': function(e) {
 //Check if facebook event was already imported
      Meteor.call('hasEventWithExternalId', id, function(error, result) {
          if(result){
            return swal({
                    title: "Event already imported from Facebook",
                    text: "That facebook event was already imported to this application",
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    type: "error"
                });
          }

      });

      //Check if it is a valid facebook event
      Meteor.call('isValidFacebookEvent', id, function(error, result) {
          if(!result){
            return swal({
                    title: "Invalid Facebook event",
                    text: "That's not a valid facebook event'",
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    type: "error"
                });   
          }
      });

       Meteor.call('importEventFromFacebook', id, function(error, result) {
          if(error){
            console.log(error);
            return false;
          }
          else{
            return swal({
                    title: "Event sucessfully imported",
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    type: "success"
                });   
          }
      });

    }
```

One of the methods:

```
Meteor.methods({

  //Check if Event with external id x already exists
  hasEventWithExternalId: function(externalId){
    if(Event.find({externalId: externalId}).count()>0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe adding your `Meteor.methods()` code could help in understanding your situation.

Comment: i added a method @ghybs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are executing your 3 `Meteor.call()` no matter what is the result of your 2 checks.

Therefore, even if your `"hasEventWithExternalId"` call returns `true` (i.e. it could find an event already imported, like the 2nd time you fire your button click event), your other calls will still be executed, in particular your `"importEventFromFacebook"` call that will try to (re-)import your FB event.

You should perform your next `Meteor.call()` only if the previous one did not return an error / result that say not to continue, e.g. in an `else` block.

For example:

```js
  Meteor.call('hasEventWithExternalId', id, function(error, result) {
      if (error) return;

      if (result){
          return swal({
                title: "Event already imported from Facebook",
                text: "That facebook event was already imported to this application",
                showConfirmButton: true,
                type: "error"
            });
      } else {
          Meteor.call('isValidFacebookEvent', id, function (error, result {
              // etc.
          });
      }

  });
```

But in the first place, why not doing all this directly server-side, in a single `Meteor.methods()`, instead of having to execute 3 different calls?

Comment: i tought that the "return" would stop the execution

Comment: The `return` stops the execution of the callback only. But the callback may be executed once your 3 `Meteor.call()` are already performed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call